# Brand class sits outside of the navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you take a look here:

http://www.dealerbyte.co.uk/

I've just been testing things out on my local server and for some reason my brand class is overflowing the container and I have no idea why. I've tried changing a couple of things in the CSS however I can't seem to get it inside. I'm suspecting it's a padding or margin problem.

Here is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-6">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="media/images/logo.png" alt="Driven Car Sales Logo" class="img-rounded logo-nav navbar-brand"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.logo-custom {
height: 2em;
}

.logo-nav {
height: 4em;
}
.brand {
font-size: 2em;
color: #ff0066;
margin: 20px 0 25px;
}
.navbar-brand {
opacity: 0;
color: #ff0066;
transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
.navbar {
border-radius: 0;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
}
nav.affix {
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
}
nav.affix .navbar-brand {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Any idea why this is happening I am stumped?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's because the logo is overflowing the navbar. For a simple fix, you can use negative `margin-top` to `.logo-nav`, and also set `padding-top` to `0`. You would also to change `height` of `.logo-nav` to `2em`, since `4em` would make it so big, even bigger than `.logo-custom`.

```
.logo-nav {
    height: 2em;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Here is the [**demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cuplizian/h6wnk/).

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes got the problem 
you can solve than by removing `.navbar-brand` class from  tag around your logo just give that class to logo is fine

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-6">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <!-- I mean Here -->
        <a href="/"><img src="media/images/logo.png" alt="Driven Car Sales Logo" class="img-rounded logo-nav navbar-brand"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

and know give the `.navbar-brand` class font-size of 12px

```
.navbar-brand {
float: left;
height: 50px;
padding: 15px 15px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you both! Awesome help!

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not get what your problem is again I tried to help you if you are saying that why logo is not showing in brand the answer is this that

the `.navbar-brand` Opacity is equal to 0

```
.navbar-brand {
opacity: 0;
color: #ff0066;
transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
```

remove that

```
.navbar-brand {
color: #ff0066;
transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
```

remove the picture from above you have added two image one in brand and the other one is above nav the large one

Comment: The logo does show when it's scrolled. Scroll down and you will understand my problem. Sorry for not being more clear.